# How to add a image to a product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am trying to use this extension to add a image to a attribute

https://github.com/aligent/magento-attribute-option-image

added attribute 'brands' using the above exstension i set a image per brand

in the sql i got image and thumb column inside of `mage_eav_attribute_option` that contains a url to the image

how can i display this on the products view page